# Customizing Authorization on resource endpoints in Python EVE

Tags: python, web-services, python-2.7, eve

I have implemented my web-service in Python eve . I have several endpoints like people , address etc .

The endpoints schema definition is as follows :-

```
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']

ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

people = {
  'item_title': 'person',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people,
  'public_methods': ['POST']
  }

org = {
  'item_title': 'org',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_org
  }

puburl = {
  'item_title': 'puburl',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_pub_url
  }

address = {
  'item_title': 'address',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_address
 }

contactnumber = {
  'item_title': 'contactnumber',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_contact_number
 }

template = {
  'item_title': 'template',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_template
 }

usersharedcontacts = {
  'item_title': 'usersharedcontacts',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_with_user_shared_contacts
 }

cardholder = {
  'item_title': 'cardholder',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people_card_holder
 }

DOMAIN = {
  'people': people,
  'org': org,
  'puburl': puburl,
  'address': address,
  'contactnumber': contactnumber,
  'template': template,
  'usersharedcontacts': usersharedcontacts,
  'cardholder': cardholder
 }
```

I have implemented Authentication to make `POST` call on the `people` endpoint to be free , i.e. a user profile can be created without any authentication required and the `people` table in the DB would be populated .

I now want to make sure that once a user is authenticated he / she should not be able to modify the other user's information. Is there a way in `Python EVE` to handle this.

`[EDIT]:- There was some bug in my code , @Niccola's Solution worked properly ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [User Restricted Resource Access](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access) feature. Quoting from the docs:

> When this feature is enabled, each stored document is associated with the account that created it. **This allows the API to transparently serve only account-created documents on all kinds of requests: read, edit, delete and of course create**. User authentication needs to be enabled for this to work properly.

Comment: Hi @nicola-iarocci , I went through the documentation as described on the `EVE` official Documentation page , I am not able to figure out the exact steps to pursue this approach. It would be very helpful if I can get some code snippets and exact changes required .

Comment: Your solution worked properly , Thanks for the helping me out .. :)